# Xcode 8 error: 'no such file or directory: '/Users/.../InstructionBViewController.swift'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I keep on receiving a swift compiler error 'no such file or directory: '/Users/.../InstructionBViewController.swift'I searched everywhere I tried:

1. Deleting the reference and the file itself.
2. Deleting Derived data
3. Reboot my mac
4. I do not see any red files and I deleted 'InstructionBViewController.swift' in my finder and in my file insepctor
5. When I added an exactly the same file in the same location, another error pops up 'filename "InstructionBViewController.swift"used twice'
6. Deleting all the usages of the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Open your finder go to your project directory search for "InstructionBViewController.swift" file delete it. Then in Xcode create the file "InstructionBViewController.swift".Check it whether it works you might have not removed the reference.